# Running PHP on a new apache server and Its not working

Tags: php, apache

I have an Apache server on my Mac but I recently got a PC so I'm moving my code over to it.

On my mac this code works:

**db.php**:

```
<?php
$url = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$conn = mysqli_connect("$url","$user","$pass","space");
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?
        include 'db.php';
        ?>
        <!-- Header stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Body stuff -->
        <?php
            $spaceSelect = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `world`");
            $i = 1;
            while($space = mysqli_fetch_array($spaceSelect)){
                echo "<button id='sector' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#".$space['id']."Modal'>".$space['id']."</button>";
                $i += 1;
                if($i % 10 == 1){
                    echo "<br>";
                };
                echo "stuff";
            };
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this on the new server I get the error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in S:\shared\space\index.php on line 30
```

This fixes if I move "include db.php"

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?

        ?>
        <!-- Header stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Body stuff -->
        <?php
            include 'db.php';
            $spaceSelect = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `world`");
            $i = 1;
            while($space = mysqli_fetch_array($spaceSelect)){
                echo "<button id='sector' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#".$space['id']."Modal'>".$space['id']."</button>";
                $i += 1;
                if($i % 10 == 1){
                    echo "<br>";
                };
                echo "stuff";
            };
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is really annoying me and I wasn't getting this error when the server was on my Mac. Is there something I need to change in httpd.conf?

Comment: What are your PHP versions on the Mac and on the PC?

Comment: are you using windows now?

Comment: password in mac mamp is root & in windows it's default empty check it's your password ok

Comment: Version 5.6.30 on my mac and 7.1.7 on windows

Comment: did you give the correct user name and password for windows? in win it's root and there\s no password.

Comment: I would guess that your connection in `$conn = mysqli_connect("$url","$user","$pass","space");` is not working properly for some reason.

Comment: When i move the include out of the header it works, But when its in the header it doesnt

Comment: Check that it can find 'db.php', I tend to use `require_once` as this will stop with an error if it can't find the include file.

Comment: Find the `php.ini` file and
You should find a line that says `short_open_tag = Off` change this to:
`short_open_tag = On`
If the line doesn't exist just add it.  After editing php.ini file restart the apache service

Comment: @JYoThI that seems to of fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** Find the `php.ini` file and
You should find a line that says

`short_open_tag = Off`

change this to:

`short_open_tag = On`

If the line doesn't exist just add it.

**2nd :**  After editing `php.ini` file restart the apache service

Comment: Sweet, This fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad it help you @Puffycheeses

Answer (score 0):

try a include_once in the header section. Normally, changes in the httpd.conf are only needed if you use sub folders.

Comment: problem fixed above, php-tag problem